# 301 redirect containing a specific keyword remove filters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Somehow a lot of layered navigation URLs were indexed by google and resulted in thousands of crawl errors.

In order to resolve that, I want to 301 redirect following url containing a keyword "Filter"

> https://www.example.com/some-url-key/Filter/brand/Brand
> 1/dir/asc/order/more-parameters/Parameter1,Parameter2/
>
> https://www.example.com/some-url-key-2/Filter/brand/Brand
> 1/dir/asc/order/more-parameters/Parameter1,Parameter2/

to

> https://www.example.com/some-url-key/
>
> https://www.example.com/some-url-key-2/ (correspondingly)

and remove additional filters from URL to keep it more SEO friendly.

The rewrite rule I made so far is,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Filter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/some-url-key [L,R=301,NC]
```

But in the RewriteRule, I want the "some-url-key" part to be dynamic , unlike what I have now is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/filter/.+$ /$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Change R to R=301 when you are sure the Redirect is working ok.

Comment: I would also appreciate if you could give me a manual / documentation about where I could get more understanding for such kind of regular expressions